# Rails - Function - Reusable Code Block - How to? - refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, refactoring, codeblocks

I have written code that i wrote myself that i need to rewrite as a short block. I have 8 models and am creating a table of related ids. So I run through a piece of code that is the same except that for each model/object instance there are 7 things to work with. So this is like a cycle out of 8 select 1, do something same with the other 7. then pickup next from the seven and continue. I have no idea what to call this task - refactoring, functions etc. Am new to web programming 3 months and need some help. I know it can be done, as i used to program 8 years ago. Code blocks below.
Models are (tales, morals, values, books, keywords, characters)
this piece of code is repeated for all the things one at a time. So what i want to do is simply pass a word to the function and it should not only use that as a parameter, but also use it to generate code. example in the case below i want to pass MORAL and the rest of the code should be generated on its own.

```
moral_ids_to_delete = A(@tale_relation.moral_ids) - @moral_ids

  moral_ids_to_delete.each do |id|
       moral = TaleRelation.find_by(field: 'moral_ids', moral_ids: id)
      @value_relations.each do |relation|
       if A(moral.tale_ids) - A(relation.tale_ids) == [] then
         moral.value_ids = S(A(moral.value_ids) -        A(@tale_relation.value_ids) + A(relation.value_ids))
       else
         relation.moral_ids = S(A(relation.moral_ids) - A(id))
       end
  end
  @book_relations.each do |relation|
    if A(moral.tale_ids) - A(relation.tale_ids) == [] then
      moral.book_ids = S(A(moral.book_ids) - A(@tale_relation.book_ids) + A(relation.book_ids))
    else
      relation.moral_ids = S(A(relation.moral_ids) - A(id))
    end
  end
  @keyword_relations.each do |relation|
    if A(moral.tale_ids) - A(relation.tale_ids)  == [] then
      moral.keyword_ids = S(A(moral.keyword_ids) - A(@tale_relation.keyword_ids) + A(relation.keyword_ids))
    else
      relation.moral_ids = S(A(relation.moral_ids) - A(id))
    end
  end
  @character_relations.each do |relation|
    if A(moral.tale_ids) - A(relation.tale_ids) == [] then
      moral.character_ids = S(A(moral.character_ids) - A(@tale_relation.character_ids) + A(relation.character_ids))
    else
      relation.moral_ids = S(A(relation.moral_ids) - A(id))
    end
  end
  moral.tale_ids = S(A(moral.tale_ids) - @tale_ids)
  moral.update(tale_ids: moral.tale_ids, value_ids: moral.value_ids, book_ids: moral.book_ids, keyword_ids: moral.keyword_ids, character_ids: moral.character_ids)
end
```

Comment: You should consider posting this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, at first look I thought this was a simple "Extract method" transformation. If you have rubymine, you could do this interactively. But then I saw that the `_ids` method changed, so we add that as an extra parameter, and to call it we just do

```
moral.send(:character_ids)
```

which is equivalent to `moral.character_ids`.

So we define a function (I have no idea what your code does, `S`? `A`? so you should choose a more sensible function-name)

```
def update_ids_or_relation(id, moral, relation, association)
  if A(moral.tale_ids) - A(relation.tale_ids) == [] then
    moral.send(association) = 
      S( A(moral.send(association)) - A(@tale_relation.send(association)) + A(relation.send(association)) )
  else
    relation.moral_ids = S(A(relation.moral_ids) - A(id))
  end
end
```

This could be refactored a bit for readability, but again, it is easier to choose meaningful names if you know what the code is supposed to do. So I left it like that.

And then your code simply becomes

```
moral_ids_to_delete = A(@tale_relation.moral_ids) - @moral_ids

moral_ids_to_delete.each do |id|
  moral = TaleRelation.find_by(field: 'moral_ids', moral_ids: id)

  @value_relations.each do |relation|
    update_ids_or_relation(id, moral, relation, :value_ids)
  end 
  @book_relations.each do |relation|
    update_ids_or_relation(id, moral, relation, :book_ids)
  end
  @keyword_relations.each do |relation|
    update_ids_or_relation(id, moral, relation, :keyword_ids)
  end
  @character_relations.each do |relation|
    update_ids_or_relation(id, moral, relation, :character_ids)
  end

  moral.tale_ids = S(A(moral.tale_ids) - @tale_ids)
  moral.save
end
```

Also I simplified the last line: because the values are all set correctly, we can just save the `moral`.

Comment: I was searching for a method like .send() - Thanks    Next bit now - if in a piece of code block I have a piece of string being repeated many time say like @ morals, @ moral_ids, .moral_ids, @ moral_relations, 'moral_ids' is there a way i can write code that i pass the code block simple 'moral' and it substitutes it in all the places . I basically builds up the code.

Comment: Using `send` you just send a method-name to the object. So you can just string interpolation to build your method-name. So write something like `a.send("#{part_name}_ids")`.